# react-testing-library | Cannot Split Test into smaller chunks inside describe method

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm learning about unit testing React components using [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library)

I have the component rendering correctly, however, when I aim to break the test into smaller chunks inside a `describe()` function. The test breaks and here's why.

Current only one or the other `test()` passes but not both

```
import React from 'react'
import 'react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each'
import { render, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library'
import Quantity from '../components/Quantity'

describe('Quantity Component', () => {
  const { container, getByTestId } = render(<Quantity />)

// first test
  test('checks that quantity is never 0', () => {
    expect(getByTestId('quantity')).not.toBe('0')
  })

// second test
  test('checks for the initial product quantity count', () => {
    expect(getByTestId('quantity')).toHaveTextContent('1')

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('increment'))
    expect(getByTestId('quantity')).toHaveTextContent('2')
  })
})
```

When trying to run both tests it errors:
`Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="quantity"]`

`[data-testid="quantity"]` is just an attribute that I passed inside my desired JSX tag.

The test passes when running **only** the first or second test but not **both** concurrently.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-contamination is strictly discouraged in unit testing.

The problem is that a setup occurs only once per `Quantity Component` suite, while it should be done for each test. This is what `beforeEach` is for:

```
describe('Quantity Component', () => {
  let container, getByTestId;

  beforeEach(() => {
    ({ container, getByTestId } = render(<Quantity />));
  });
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try your suggestion instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also use an afterEach cleanup.

```
describe('your tests', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  beforeEach(() => ({container, getById} = render(<Quantity />))

  it('does something', () => {
    expect(getByTestId('quantity')).toHaveTextContent(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jameson, will do that instead now. However, you did you see that I'm already importing on top of the file `import 'react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each'` Shouldn't that mitigate this situation?

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you call the `render` inside your `it` clauses, it keeps the tests easier to manage:

```
describe('Quantity Component', () => {  
  test('checks that quantity is never 0', () => {
    const { container, getByTestId } = render(<Quantity />)
    expect(getByTestId('quantity')).not.toBe('0')
  })

  test('checks for the initial product quantity count', () => {
    const { container, getByTestId } = render(<Quantity />)
    expect(getByTestId('quantity')).toHaveTextContent('1')

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('increment'))
    expect(getByTestId('quantity')).toHaveTextContent('2')
  })
})
```

The added advantage is that if for some reason one of your tests needs to run with different props you can do that more easily with this setup.